# Conditionally execute a funtion, throws error `Conditions must have a static type of 'bool'. Try changing the condition`

Tags: flutter

I want to feed `Two` to the `function`. When function receives `Two` as the data, it should print `success` to the console. But seems like it's not the correct way.

**Error:** `Conditions must have a static type of 'bool'. Try changing the condition.`

**List**

```
enum ButtonList {One, Two, Three}
```

**Calling function**

```
testFunc(ButtonList.Two)),
```

**Function**

```
testFunc( ButtonList type) {

 if (type = ButtonList.Two ){print('sucess ')};
  
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```dart
testFunc(ButtonList type) {
  if (type == ButtonList.Two) {
    print('sucess ')
  };  
}
```

There's a big difference between `=` (assigning a value to a variable) and `==` (equality comparison). `if` expects a condition (`==`), not the assigning operation (`=`).

Formatting is important to read and understand the code. Please read Dart best code style practices: https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style

Comment: It shows `type 'Null' is not a subtype of type Function'`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign with =, use == instead